# Terminology conventions in optimization

Tags: optimization, terminology

I am writing a paper on optimization and was wondering if it is acceptable to say, for example, "There are many local **minimums**" or should it be phrased to say "There are many local **minima**"?   Are minima and minimums exchangeable vocabulary? Or is there a difference?

Comment: They mean the same thing; they are both plurals of "minimum".  It is standard to say "minima", but I have seen "minimums".

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minimum Definition 2 is pretty funny (probably an attempt to be comprehensive by one of the authors who had taken calculus, which is of course *the cutting edge of mathematics*, or at least was 350 years ago), but this dictionary does indicate that both are correct pluralizations of "minimum" in English.

Comment: *minima* is all-but universally used as the plural, at least in a technical context (the OED has only one citation that includes *minimums*, and about 15 with *minima*, for example, and they'll go out of their way to find a examples of uncommon usage). *minima* is six times as common on the Internet, if you believe Google, and that's in general usage, not mathematics. Cf. [Google's book collection's numbers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minima%2Cminimums&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminima%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminimums%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Just don't get me started on *in vacuo*, which is often incorrectly given as **in vacuum*, which is neither correct Latin nor correct English in almost any context in which people use it.

Comment: If I were refereeing your paper, I would comment that "minimums" should read "minima" to agree with standard scientific and technical usage.

Comment: Awesome, thanks everyone who commented. I'll go with minima. Anyone want to submit that as an answer?

Comment: @RustyStatistician: Why not submit it as an answer yourself (your conclusion from your survey)?

Comment: @RobArthan well I was hoping to reward someone but I could do that too.

Comment: ___ **minima** ___

Comment: @Chappers: Sorry, I'm curious, so I'll have to get you started: I can't think of any context that makes "in vacuum" correct English. (Presumably it's correct in Latin when "in" means "into".)

Comment: @RobArthan Cheap trick answer: vacuum used as part of a noun phrase, such as "In vacuum polarisation, we have [...]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Minima* is all-but universally used as the plural, at least in a technical context (the OED has only one citation that includes minimums, and about 15 with minima, for example, and they'll go out of their way to find a examples of uncommon usage). minima is six times as common on the Internet, if you believe Google, and that's in general usage, not mathematics. Cf. [Google's book collection's numbers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minima%2Cminimums&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminima%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminimums%3B%2Cc0).